# Generating shortest route from A to B (polygons) using Network analyst using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, network-analyst, arcgis-10.7

I am trying to make a model that generates the shortest route from polygon A to polygon B with network analyst using ArcMap ModelBuilder. I have managed to get the model to work using point data (point A to point B) but not with polygons. Please advice

[image]

Comment: Without any context to what your network is or your what your polygons represent we can only guess a best approach. I would suggest you start by looking to extract the centroids of your polygons and they become the stops that snap to the network?

Comment: That worked, thanks!